# Python mysql dynamic add column and update values in the new columns

Tags: python, mysql, dynamic

```
for i in onlycolumns:
if i not in pat and i not in ref:
    new=lister.index(i)
    value1 = lister[new+1]
    query="ALTER TABLE test add %s varchar(30)" %i
    cursor.execute(query)

    query1 = """ UPDATE test
           SET % = %s
            WHERE patient_name = %s """
    data = (i,value1,value)
    cursor.execute(query1, data)
```

The columns are added dynamically but the values are not updated  in it ...any wrong with my update command......**value** variable here is the name of patient name ...it is right and the value in **value1** is 'a'.pLEASE HELP ME ANYONE
WITH THE UPDATE COMMAND

Comment: Maybe, you need a commit in your query. the commit is with the connection, no with the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The problema is with the SET: Use
SET %s = %s.

You miss the the s near one %.

Comment: The other problem I see is that your data tuple have 3 values but you have just 2 positions to replace (the %s). To determine the final issue, could you please print the command that will be executed before execute?