# MariaDB dynamically adding columns to existing table

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-python, pymysql

I have a python scrypt that looks for data from the web. Sometimes this can create the need for new tables to be added to an existing table. I'm using pymysql and I've tried some examples found online but unfortunately I keep getting stuck with errors. It seems that simply my SQL query is faulty but I have no idea how to fix the issue.

```
for j in range(1, counter + 1):
    if missing_matrix[j] !=  0:
        print("adding: ", missing_matrix[j])
        connection = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@server:3306/db').connect()
        print ('//////////////////// connected to mysql:')
        query = ("ALTER TABLE price_usd "
                "ADD IF NOT EXISTS new DOUBLE "
                "VALUES (%s)")
        query_data = (missing_matrix[j])
        connection.execute(query, query_data)

        connection.close()

return
```

Once the code works I plan to make the connection once of the entire iteration.

The column will contain numerical values once they are added.

The error I get is a whole newspaper worth of red lines, but this piece looks the most noteworthy:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('ballpoint pen')' at line 1") [SQL: 'ALTER TABLE price_usd ADD IF NOT EXISTS new DOUBLE VALUES (%s)'] [parameters: ('ballpoint pen',)]`

Comment: Please include the exact error output as well.

Comment: I would start checking the mysql manual on alter table first, if I were you. Your syntax is not even close to the required one.

Comment: Tanks for your reply, I added the error code.

Comment: And you are using mariadb, not mysql. Pls word and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought mariaDB and mysql were very similar, also in syntax, fyi I downloaded it through xampp as mysql equipped. I checked the default manual but there is nothing in it that would suspect my query to be wrong. As I see it it receives the name that is to be added.

Comment: I have seen this in another question asked on this site:
query = "ALTER TABLE upload ADD %s INT(15)" % (colName)
c.execute( query )
But it is not dyanmic.

Comment: Lastly I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956991/python-mysql-dynamic-add-column-and-update-values-in-the-new-columns
But I have no idea how to implement that code into mine.

Comment: `"I checked the default manual but there is nothing in it that would suspect my query to be wrong"` Then check again. Since when does alter table have a values clause?

Comment: You may need an insert statement as opposed to an alter table.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

> ```
> #   adding missing entities to mysql database
> connection = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@server:3306/db').connect()
> for j in range(1, counter + 1):
>     if missing_matrix[j] !=  0:            
>         query1 = ("ALTER TABLE price_usd ADD IF NOT EXISTS %s DOUBLE ") %(missing_matrix[j])
>         connection.execute(query1)
> Connection.close
> ```

The problem I had was that my column names had spaces in their names. I wrote another function that replaces these spaces with a _ then it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can use backticks to use spaces in identifiers: `create database \`drop database\`;`

Comment: Yet is works perfectly now, running for a couple of days stable